# [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element <navigation-drawer> - did you register the component correctly?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

I imported two components from a custom library. When running "npm run serve" I don't get any errors in the cmd but when I open localhost it's a white screen and the console says

"[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in 
--->  at src/App.vue 
"

Here's App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
<navigation-drawer/>
<TFFooter/>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import NavigationDrawer from 'library'
import TFFooter from 'library'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    NavigationDrawer,
    TFFooter
  }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your component to NavigationDrawer to 'navigation-drawer':NavigationDrawer,

Comment: The tag in <template>?

Comment: you can change the component to `'navigation-drawer':NavigationDrawer` or changed you template `<NavigationDrawer>`